# Basic Vue help: Accessing JS object values in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I’ve been experimenting with vue.js and I'm having difficulty accessing JS object values in components when routing.

Using this repo to experiment, https://github.com/johnayeni/filter-app-vue-js, I'm just trying to replicate a basic a “product list” and “product description” app, but I can't get it working. The repo's homepage (the SearchPage.vue component) serves as the "product list," and I'm just trying to add the "product description" component to display only one item at a time.

I've added a "description page" component (calling it "item.vue") to allow a user to click on one of the languages/frameworks that will then route to item.vue to just display that specific object's associated information (item.name, item.logo, etc.), i.e., and not display any of the other languages.

Following some tutorials, here's what I've tried:

First, I added ids to the JS objects (found in data/data.js), i.e., **id:'1'**.

```
const data = [
 {
    id: '1',
    name: 'vue js',
    logo: 'http://... .png',
    stack: [ 'framework', 'frontend', 'web', 'mobile' ],
 },
 {
    id: '2',
    name: 'react js',
    logo: 'http://... .png',
    stack: [ 'framework', 'frontend', 'web', 'mobile' ]
 },
...
];
export default data
```

Then, I wrapped the item.name (in ItemCard.vue) in router-link tags:

```
<router-link :to="'/item/'+item.id"> {{ item.name}} </router-link>
```

I then added a new path in router/index.js:

```
{
path: './item/:id', 
component: item,
props: true
}
```

But, when that router-link is clicked I can only access the ".id" (via $route.params.id), but I can't get .name or .logo. How do I access the other values (i.e. item.name, item.logo, etc.)? I have a feeling I'm going down the wrong track here.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you want your object to be available for use in other components, consider using a store: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/ You would keep your object in the store and you will be able to access it via computed property in your components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just need a wrapper component that takes the desired item from the URL and renders the proper item. Let's say an ItemWrapper:

```
<template>
  <item-card :item="item"></item-card>
</template>

<script>
import ItemCard from './ItemCard.vue';
import data from '../data/data';

export default {
  components: {
    ItemCard,
  },
  props: {
    stackNameUrl: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: {},
    }
  },
  computed: {
    stackName() {
      return decodeURI(this.stackNameUrl);
    }

  },
  created() {
    this.item = data.find( fw => fw.name === this.stackName);
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This component takes a prop which is a stack/fw name uri encoded, decodes it, finds the fw from data based on such string, and renders an `ItemCard` with the fw item.

For this to work we need to setup the router so `/item/vue js` f.i. renders `ItemWrapper` with 'vue js' as the `stackNameUrl` prop. To do so, the important bit is to set `props` as true:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import SearchPage from '@/components/SearchPage';
import ItemWrapper from '@/components/ItemWrapper';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'SearchPage',
      component: SearchPage
    },
    {
      path: '/item/:stackNameUrl',
      name: 'ItemWrapper',
      component: ItemWrapper,
      props: true,
    },
  ]
});
```

Now we need to modify `SearchPage.vue` to let the stack boxes act as links. Instead of:

```
<!-- iterate data -->
      <item-card v-for="(item, index) in filteredData" :key="index" :item="item"></item-card>
```

we now place:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in filteredData" >
  <router-link :to="'/item/' + item.name" :key="index">
    <item-card  :key="index" :item="item"></item-card>
  </router-link>
</template>
```

So now every component is placed within a link to `item/name`.

And voilá.

Some considerations:

- the `:param` is key for the vue router to work. You wanted to use it to render the `ItemCard` itself. That could work, but you would need to retrieve the fw from data from the component `created()`. This ties your card component with `data.js` which is bad, because such component is meant to be reusable, and take an `item` param is much better than go grabbing data from a file in such scenario. So a `ItemWrapper` was created that sort of proxies the request and pick the correct framework for the card.
- You should still check for cases when an user types a bad string.
- Explore Vue in depth before going for vuex solutions. Vuex is great but usually leads to brittle code and shouldn't be overused.

Comment: Hi @Sergeon, thank you so much -- that helped SO MUCH! But, I do have one issue I can't seem to resolve and would appreciate any help. Since the new path is `path: '/item/:stackNameUrl',` I'd like to replace white space in the URL with `-`s and convert to lower-case, but I can't figure out where/how. I've tried adding `.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();` to numerous places but haven't achieved my desired results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Filled a PR directly in the repo to avoid discussing here in the comments :-)

Comment: Thank you, yet again. I appreciate your time and clarity on this very much.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason you have access the `id` because it's an url param: `./item/:id`.

You have a couple options here, which depends on what you're trying to accomplish:

---

As suggested by @dziraf, you can use `vuex` to create a store, which in turn would give you access to all the data at any point in your app:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    data() {
      return this.$store.data;
    }
  }
}
```

Learn more here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

---

As an alternative, you can just import your data, and grab the correct item by its `id`:

```
import data from './data.js';

export default {
  computed: {
    data() {
      return data.find(d => d.id === this.$route.params.id);
    }
  }
}
```

Just depends on what you're trying to do.